# problem printing a one page site

Tags: css, wordpress, printing, themes, slider

I just got this wordpress theme:
http://meezio.pixelworkshop.fr/

Very nice, the problem is that since it's a one page template whenever I try to print the page I'm currently viewing it always prints the first page, I understand why the browser does this and it is working as intended, but is there a way to print exactly whats on the screen at the moment to request to print page?

BTW I changed the media="screen" to media="all" to all stylesheets so the styles are displaying correctly on the printed pages, but still shows me the first slide no matter what. If you go the the blog section or any category it works fine though, since these pages don't have the slide feature.

Does anyone know how could I do this?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843595/print-visible-screen-only) with a *suggested solution*

> - Give the body and the HTML tag 100% height
> - Give the body a "overflow: hidden"
> - Put the contents of your page into a 100% wide, 100% tall DIV with
>     overflow:auto
> - Scroll to the desired position and click "print"

The important part is that there is no clear solution to this problem, but with a bit of trickery, you can try to accomplish what you need.

Additional reading: [Restricting printing to selected HTML elements only](http://javascript.about.com/library/blprint.htm) or [see here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/create_printer_friendly_web_page_using_media_attribute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but that got me to the part where I'm only printing the first page, I see he got it to work but he doesn't say how :(